# According to Catholicism, if we sin and become repentant will our sins be forgiven too like St. Peter?

Tags: catholicism, sin, confession, forgiveness, purgatory

At the catechism class we learned that as Peter was repentant after betraying Jesus his sin was forgiven.

If we sin, become repentant and do confessions will our sins be forgiven too? Or do we have to go through purgatory?

Comment: Was there anything specific that made you think God might not forgive us when we repent? Isn't that the core of the Gospel?

Comment: @curiousdannii When King David had sinned he repented and touched the ark of the covenant that only Levites could touch. Still he lost his two sons and wife left him. So...

Comment: Being forgiven by God and escaping all consequences are two very different things.

Comment: @curiousdannii He said before ark of the covenant bleach me with the biggest sop. Still God didn't forgive him. I think God hates cheating, murder and extramarital affairs. Don't you think so?

Answer (score 1):

You may have to go through purgatory, but that is not the same thing as your sins remaining unforgiven. If your sins were not forgiven, you would go to hell.

When you repent of your sins, go to confession for them, and make a firm resolution not to sin in the future, God forgives you. You are now in the state of "sanctifying grace." Your soul is infused with grace and cannot pass into hell, unless you commit a mortal sin, at which point you willingly reject God's grace and take yourself out of this state. Repentance, confession, and a firm resolution will restore you to the state of grace. God has promised this to us.

Purgatory is thought of by theologians in two different ways. It can be a temporary debt paid as a consequence of sin for those who have been forgiven (as opposed to the eternal debt of hell). It can also be the pain of detachment from worldly goods that the soul in purgatory must put behind him before he can enjoy the beatific vision. In my opinion, purgatory is probably both of these together.